# Javascript AJAX Post to Java REST

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, rest

I am trying to POST to this Spring REST service that I have set up which will accept a `Review` object. I can easily test this in Java as I can create an actual `Review` object and it will successfully create into the database. The issue is when I am trying to do it in Javascript I get a `415 Unsupported Media Type` error. I know this has to do with how I am creating my `Review` object in Javascript but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**index.js code snippet**

```
function submitReview() {
    var rating = $('#rating-review input:radio:checked').val();

    var newReview = new Review(Number($('#id-review').val()), rating, $('#message-text').val());

    console.log(newReview);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/review",
        data: newReview,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 'success')
                alert("Successfully submitted review");
            else
                alert("Unsuccessful Review Submission");
        }
    });
}

function Review(carId, rating, review)
{
    this.carId = carId;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.review = review;
}
```

**ReviewRestService.java code snippet**

```
@POST
@Path("/review")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String addReview(Review review) {
    reviewService.addReview(review);

    return review.getId();
}
```

I have tried changing my `submitReview()` to be...

```
function submitReview() {

    var newReview = {
        "carId": 123,
        "rating": 2,
        "review": "testing"
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/review",
        data: newReview,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 'success')
                alert("Successfully submitted review");
            else
                alert("Unsuccessful Review Submission");
        }
    });
}
```

as a test, but I still receive the same error. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'` to your AJAX parameters

Comment: hmmm... I just tried adding that and `dataType: 'application/json`. Both still give me the same 415 error. Is there something that I am not seeing? Should I provide more information now that it didn't work?